# What happens if the Queen and the striker are pocketed together and there are no other pieces on the board?

Tags: carrom

The case seems a bit complicated. The Queen is the only piece remaining on the board. All Men are pocketed. Both the Queen and the striker got pocketed in the same pot. What should happen then?

Should the player return a Man? If he returns one, should he immediately take a turn and strike the returned Man to try to cover the Queen? Or should he return the Queen anyway?

Answer (score 2):

**This can't happen.**

From [these rules](http://www.mastersgames.com/rules/carrom-rules.htm), the Queen can't be left without a piece from each team still being on the board.

Pocketing **either player's** final piece with the Queen still on the board is a foul, which returns the pocketed piece and a penalty piece.

If the Queen and the striker were pocketed together while pieces were left, this is also a foul. Since a foul ends the turn, this means that the Queen can't then be covered, so it will return to the board.

However, from [the ICF rules](http://icf-media.beepworld.de/laws-of-carrom.htm):

Somebody will already have won. Pocketing your own, or your opponent's final piece while the Queen is on the board causes you to lose.